# Docker volume not being mounted in container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to mount a volume using docker-compose so I can hot reload some C code when developing. I've used Docker a couple times before and specifically hit this use case while working on a nodejs website but I'm completely at a loss here.

My `docker-compose.yml` and `Dockerfile` have been stripped down entirely to just the bare minimum. I would like to mount my current directory (all source code) into the container. My `Dockerfile` just installs some dependencies, sets the working directory and then attempts to run the makefile while my `docker-compose.yml` adds the volume. The result is a container that cannot access the mounted volume and resulting code (it's nothing wrong with the Makefile as it works on the host directory and when copied in, instead of using a volume). Does anyone see anything wrong with either of these files? It appears the `/cfs` folder isn't even being created in the container. I tried mounting it to the home directory to no avail.

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  cfs:
    volumes:
      - ./:/cfs
    build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks:
      - default
  
networks:
  default:
    internal: true
```

### Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

# install dependencies
RUN apt-get -qy update                           \
    && apt-get -y install                        \
        cmake=3.16.3-1ubuntu1                    \
        make=4.2.1-1.2                           \
        gcc=4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2                     \
        g++=4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2

WORKDIR /cfs

RUN make prep
RUN make
RUN make install
```

Comment: Looks like that this should work. As a first step to analyze this you might want to replace ./ with ${PWD} in your volume definition to see if that makes a difference. In some environments ./ and ${PWD} return different values.

Answer (score 3):

Most Compose settings aren't visible during an image build.  `volumes:` aren't mounted, `environment:` variables aren't set, `networks:` aren't accessible.  Only the settings within the immediate `build:` block have an effect.

That means you should look at the Dockerfile in isolation, ignoring the `docker-compose.yml` file.  At that point, the `/cfs` directory is empty (you don't `COPY` any source code into it), so the `RUN make ...` commands will fail.  It doesn't matter that the directory will eventually have something else mounted over it.

If you're just planning to recompile the application when the source code changes, delete the `volumes:`, `COPY` the source into the image, and run `docker-compose build` at the point you'd typically run `make`.  If you do have a setup that can rebuild the application when its source changes, you need to set the image's `CMD` to launch that, but if you don't `COPY` the source in, you can't build it at image build time.  (...and if you're going to overwrite the entire interesting content of the image with a volume, it will get lost anyways.)

Comment: OP specifically mentioned that hot-reloads during development are wanted. So they do need the Dockerfile COPY step to deal with the initial build and they need to retain the volume: mount.

Comment: So I'm thinking I should wrap all the make commands in a filewatcher script that runs them as necessary and have that be the entry point?